# Share internet through otg-ethernet from terminal

Tags: networking, usb-on-the-go, tethering

I know other threads already exist but none of them answer this specifically.

My OTG ethernet cable works only when used as a client, i.e. when a DHCP server is recognized.

I want to be able to share my 4G connexion to a router trough the WAN port. Android doesn't support this natively, so I'm guessing I'll have to create my own AP but I'm not sure exactly how do that trough the terminal.

I'm guessing there is some NAT involved.

Comment: I already commented on your previous question: [Use an external WIFI dongle as a hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/237320/use-an-external-wifi-dongle-as-a-hotspot)

Comment: This is different I never asked about a wifi dongle

Comment: There's no difference in network configuration of a WiFi dongle or Ethernet adapter. Both are connected through USB, both appear as a network interface.

Comment: I'm trying to use rmneet_data1 as AP but the mask is /30 should I adjust accordingly ?

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to do. `rmnet_data1` naming convention is used for Mobile Data network interfaces on devices with Qualcomm modems. You cannot use Mobile Data (but WiFi) interface as AP. Then NAT the traffic between both interfaces for internet sharing. Or you may even avoid NATing, but it's complicated setup: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218562/218526

Comment: Sorry I meant as upstream, ethernet is the AP