# How to exclude a specific destination IP from VPN?

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot, android-11, openvpn

I want to route a specific IP address from hotspot (`wlan0`) to Mobile Data (`rmnet_data1`) interface on Android 11, bypassing VPN.

I use my phone as a hotspot and also with the help of an app called "VPN Hotspot" I share the VPN with my PC. I want to exclude a specific IP address from VPN. I have tried the route option in "OpenVPN for Android" client and it doesn't seem to work properly. I think it might because of "Always On" enabled.

Can I achieve this with `ip route` command?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Is your device a WiFi AP? In that case every packet that appears on WiFi interface (`wlan0`) is already routed to Mobile Data interface (`rmnet_data`). Here's how you can do it manually: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217896/218526. Or if it's the opposite case i.e. route everything coming on Mobile Data to WiFi interface, here's the detailed explanation: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218562/218526

Comment: @IrfanLatif I use my phone as a hotspot and also with the help of an app called VPN Hotspot I share the VPN with my PC but I want to exclude a specific IP address from VPN but routing from the OpenVPN client didn't work so I was thinking how I can just route it with ip route add command

Comment: Got it. Note that whenever you enable or disable a VPN on Android device, routing table is recreated. There can be a score of rules added to the routing table when VPN is enabled, since it does filtering based on UIDs and Socket Marks. So you need to share the whole routing table (rules and routes) here in order to get a practical suggestion.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Just edited the question and added the table but is that the right one?

Comment: `ip -4 ru | grep -vE 'unreachable[ ]*$|local[ ]*$'; ip -4 r s t all | grep -vE '^unreachable |^local |^broadcast '`

Comment: @IrfanLatif here is the output of that command https://gist.github.com/poqdavid/a1325693f46e2c4fa399dcb2c2cba972

Comment: `ip ru add iif wlan0 lookup 9999 pri 9999; ip r add 1.2.3.4 dev rmnet_data1 table 9999`. Replace `1.2.3.4` with your required destination IP. Not tested. You might need to change RPDB priority (so that your rule is the first) and table number. Check `/data/misc/net/rt_tables` for reserved table numbers which you should not use.

Comment: Note that this routes only outgoing packets. You need to add another rule in the same way for returned traffic. And also make sure that MASQUERADE (NAT) rules are properly added (using `iptables`).

Comment: @IrfanLatif Ok that command works actually without killing my entire connection I tested this with TeamSpeak and it's actually reporting my IP I personally never used ip or iptables command can you like add this whole thing as an answer with the rule for incoming packets and the iptables MASQUERADE (NAT) I would really appreciate it

Comment: Please share your `iptables` rules: `cat /proc/net/ip_tables_names | xargs -I {} iptables -t '{}' -S`

Comment: @IrfanLatif when i run that it gives me an error saying ``xargs: unknown option 'i'`` https://gist.github.com/poqdavid/a1325693f46e2c4fa399dcb2c2cba972#file-xargs-error

Comment: Poor toybox. `cat /proc/net/ip_tables_names | while read t; do echo $t; iptables -t $t -S; done`

Comment: @IrfanLatif XD ok here got it https://gist.github.com/poqdavid/a1325693f46e2c4fa399dcb2c2cba972#file-iptables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:** The commands given below require a rooted device.*

---

Whenever you enable or disable VPN on Android device, routing table is recreated by the Android framework. There can be a score of rules added to the routing table when VPN is enabled, since it does filtering based on UIDs and Socket Marks. So you need to manipulate the routing table depending on the existing rules.

### ROUTING POLICY AND TABLES

From the info you provided, I'm quoting the relevant parts:

```
~# ip -4 rule
...
11000:  from all iif tun0 lookup local_network
...
17900:  from all iif wlan0 lookup tun0
18000:  from all iif wlan0 lookup rmnet_data1
...

~# ip -4 route show table all
...
192.168.18.0/24 dev wlan0 table local_network...
...
default via 21.62.249.109 dev rmnet_data1 table rmnet_data1...
21.62.249.104/29 dev rmnet_data1 table rmnet_data1...
...

~# iptables -t nat -S
...
-A POSTROUTING -j tetherctrl_nat_POSTROUTING
-A tetherctrl_nat_POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
-A tetherctrl_nat_POSTROUTING -o rmnet_data1 -j MASQUERADE
...
```

In simple words what the above rules state:

- Everything coming at VPN interface (`tun0`) is routed to hotspot interface (`wlan0`) if the destination IP is within hotspot subnet (`192.168.18.0/24`) i.e. the packets don't belong to the apps running on device (open sockets).
- Everything coming at hotspot interface is routed to VPN interface.
- The packets which don't qualify to be routed through VPN (mainly the VPNed traffic itself, any excluded apps, or the local packets) are routed to Mobile Data interface (`rmnet_data1`).
  `21.62.249.109` is your IP assigned by the carrier and `21.62.249.104/29` is their gateway.
- All packets going out through VPN and/or Mobile Data interfaces are MASQUERADEd i.e. their source IP address is changed from local IP to a routable IP address (`21.62.249.109` in your case).

So this is the simplified flow we are interested in:

```
Hotspot -> Routing -> FORWARD -> SNAT -> Internet
Internet -> Conntrack -> Routing -> FORWARD -> Hotspot
```

---

### SOLUTION

After understanding how it works, lets route it the way we want. Say a host on hotspot network is connecting to `1.2.3.4` through internet. But you don't want to send this specific traffic through VPN on Android device.

- Define a rule in RPDB and a routing table to route the traffic coming at hotspot interface to Mobile Data interface, if it's destined for `1.2.3.4`:

  ```
  ~# ip rule add iif wlan0 lookup 9000 pri 9999
  ~# ip route add 1.2.3.4 dev rmnet_data1 table 9000
  ```

  I used RPDB priority 9999 and table 9000. You might need to change the priority (so that your rule is always on top) and table number. Check `/data/misc/net/rt_tables` for reserved table numbers which you should not use.
- Define another rule to route the packets coming from `1.2.3.4` at Mobile Data interface to hotspot interface (if the destination IP is within hotspot subnet):

  ```
  ~# ip rule add from 1.2.3.4 iif rmnet_data1 lookup local_network pri 9999
  ```

  Note that I used here an already existing routing table `local_network`. You can define your own too.
- All outgoing packets through Mobile Data interface are already MASQUERADEd as explained above, so we don't need to add another `iptables` rule. If needed, you can also use `SNAT` target in place of `MASQUERADE`.
- Make sure that IP forwarding is enabled and allowed in firewall. Usually it's not needed because Wi-Fi hotspot already sets this up for you:

  ```
  ~# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  ~# iptables -I FORWARD -o rmnet_data1 -d 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
  ~# iptables -I FORWARD -i rmnet_data1 -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
  ```

To delete these rules use `ip rule del`, `ip route del` and `iptables -D`.

---

### NOT WORKING?

If the above rules don't work, or you need to adapt the rules for a different situation, `iptables -j LOG` is a good friend for troubleshooting.

For reference read any Linux documentation or guides about IP routing and Netfilter. It's not specifically about Android.

---

**RELATED:**

- When hotspot is enabled, every packet that appears on hotspot (Wi-Fi) interface is being routed to Mobile Data interface. Here's how to do it manually: [How to create a wifi hotspot from the terminal?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/165389)
- In the opposite case i.e. when you want to route everything coming on Mobile Data interface to WiFi interface: [How to assign Mobile Data's public IP to host connected on hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/195374)

Comment: Awesome one small thing let's say if I want to add another IP I can just add it to the same table correct? and also I think the VPN Hotspot app does the MASQUERADING if I am not wrong

Comment: Yes. // Never used that app but masquerading and forwarding is required for the native hotspot feature of Android to work. Otherwise hosts connected to hotspot won't be able to connect to internet.