# How use mobile data for internet and wifi for LAN devices in sametime at Android

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, mobile-data, android-11

I have a Samsung S21 Ultra and I want to keep both mobile data and WiFi on. My aim while doing it is using LTE for internet services(eg. Spotify, YouTube) and using wifi for LAN devices(eg. Printer, IoT devices) I don't have internet connection at WiFi router. It's just a local network.

My problem. Android's own network manager denies to use LTE when connected to any WiFi. I'm sure LTE is working in background because I have VoLTE and it's working but Android doesn't want to do internet routing with LTE when it's to WiFi connected.

How Can I route the traffic in LTE when I can still reach local printer at WiFi? Thank you.

Comment: You can't. The only way is to inject manual rules to the network routing table, which isn't possible without root. A similar question recently asked: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242015/218526

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [Unable to communicate to a local WiFi with mobile data enabled](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232561/44325)