# How can I simultaneously use mobile data and WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, mobile-data, network-signal

Through a combination of Afwall/Netguard and Automate/Tasker, I'd like to use both my mobile data and WiF at the same time.

For example, I'd like for some live/realtime widgets on the homescreen to use WiFi, but at the same time I'd like the browser session I'm on to be using mobile data.

The current setup I have is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi1ls.png) - if Chrome is on the foreground then turn of WiFi and use mobile data. When it's not in the foreground use mobile data.

But the problem with this is that it's slow. It will take a sec or two to turn off mobile data and switch on WiFi and wait for it to connect, and vise versa. If they are both on though, it wouldn't be this slow.

Any tips?

Android 7 | Rooted 1 | Xposed

Comment: On most devices, in Developer Options, there's an option called "Cellular data always active" (for fast network switching).

Comment: "(for fast network switching)" Doesn't that mean it's either or...only faster switching between them? Can I have one app use data and another use WiFi at the same time (let's say split screen working on both apps simultaneously).

Comment: Hmm, I guess I misunderstood the intent. Perhaps [the answer to a similar situation](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/171927/44325) might help, though it might not be that easy.

Comment: The question has been already asked many times e.g. here: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242307/218526

Comment: @Irfan Latif I searched, extensively, b4 posting. The only useful one I was able to find was yur linked "example". Idk, maybe others are better searchers. I saw that u also commented with the same comment on the question you linked, saying that they needed to be rooted & with a link to another question. And in that question u commented to "inject manual rules" %, as well as needing to be rooted. Perhaps u can expound a little more in my question with some more knowledge on how to do this. If anything at least this would then be the go-to reference in the future for ppl looking to do the same.

Comment: Firstly, if you did a search before posting the question, it's a better idea to add links in the question so that responders don't send you back to the same links, and mods don't close your question as a duplicate. // Secondly, good answers to such questions don't exist because the solutions are out of the scope of an ordinary user. If you've a rooted device and some prior knowledge of Linux/Android network routing, my hints are enough to reach a working solution. In other case, spending an hour or so in writing an answer that a big majority of the visitors find useless, is a wastage of time.

Comment: @Irfan Latif Thanks for your contribution.