# Change mobile phone into proxy gateway

Tags: internet, proxy

I have a WiFi network in my home. Fiber connection as default.

I'm looking for a way to hook my mobile phone into my local network, and create a "gateway" proxy on it.

I installed something called Servers Ultimate, but it does not seem to do what I need.

I want to connect to the proxy via a local WiFi connection, and then make it connect outside via LTE/3G modem.

Currently proxy works, but it redirects the connection back to the WiFi network, not through LTE.

Comment: If you have a fiber connection why do you want to route traffic through cellular?

Comment: Hi, please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restrictions on apps only. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: Hi @AndrewT. I asked about a way to do it, not about app recommendation. I only stated what I already used. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Robert Differate IP adress for testing of my webapps

Comment: The original title mentioned "Application to [...]" which is usually a big hint on app recommendation and off-topic. Fortunately, the question already mentioned the background issue, so it is clear enough to be salvaged.

Comment: *“but it redirects the connection back to the WiFi network, not through LTE*”. This issue has been discussed many times already e.g. [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/243265/218526), [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242307/218526), [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242015/218526), and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247069/218526). The problem is that Android always gives priority to WiFi when the device is connected to both WiFi and Mobile Data. You need to change the network routing table manually. It's not possible without root.

Comment: Or entirely [connect to WiFi from commandline](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219548/218526); the hard way.

Comment: @AndrewT. Sorry. Did not notice that you changed title. :) Thought it was mine.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I looked at simmiliar topics while writing this post, these did not appear.

Comment: No problem. The community is here to assist.