# Full bridge mode to pass mobile data IP to USB tethered device?

Tags: usb-tethering

I am using an old Samasung Galaxy S6 as an LTE modem, connected to a router (GL-MT1300) by USB tether. As is known, mobile data is NAT'ed on the phone and a local DHCP address is handed to the tethered device(s), resulting in double NAT on my network.

My question is, if I root the S7, is it possible to configure it as a full bridge, so that it simply passes the mobile data IP directly to the connected router? (I'm aware it will likely be a CG-NAT address and not a true public IP, this doesn't matter.)

I have seen a post regarding half-bridge mode/IP passthrough, with the assumption that the Android device still needs it's own internet connectivity, but that is not the case here. I don't need the S7 to have connectivity itself, I just want it to act like a full bridge and provide connectivity for the connected router. I would like it to work specifically over USB tether rather than wifi.

Comment: Replace the Wi-Fi interface with Ethernet interface. The rest is same as I explained: [How to assign Mobile Data's public IP to host connected on hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218562/218526)