# How does carriers blocks Internet connections on phone…

Tags: samsung, tethering, 8.1-oreo, carriers, router

I just changed my ISP, and whatever the tethering method (usb or Wi‑Fi or bluethooth) I’m using, I’m redirected to a captive portal of my carrier on my PC web browser’s stating that I’m not allowed to use my connection for tethering (everything from DNS to ping is blocked).

But when I use ʟᴛᴇ from my phone, everythings works fine…

I thought tethering works like setting up a router… How does my carrier can detect the data comes from my laptop instead of my phone ? Does rooting the phone would allows to bypass this restriction.

Comment: I didn’t installed any software from my ɪꜱᴘ. And tethering is working through the native capability of the android system.

Comment: Do realize that the data transmitted between the device and the carrier contains device identification info such as user agent - without spoofing carriers could easily catch that and respond to all illegal packages with a STOP page like what you saw.

Comment: Network operators have deep packet inspection firewalls which can guess the type of a system a request was made with. Typical PS OS additionally identify themself e.g. through the calls "home" (checking for updates...).

Comment: @Robert : DPI is illegal in my country (or at least when operated by private entities). So this isn’t that.

Comment: @AndyYan I do realize that dns requests and ping don’t have something like ʜᴛᴛᴘ user agents… So you’re completely missing the point. I finally solved the problem through changing my carrier generated ᴀᴘɴ settings at random (however internet does no longer works on the phone but at least I can perform Bluetooth reverse tethering after usb tethering).

Comment: True, my bad for omitting that part. That solution doesn't look ideal though... I know that flashing custom ROMs or even just replacing/removing certain parts of the stock ROM could eliminate the tethering restriction, but since you're asking *how* the restriction is done I have nothing more to show. (wrote a comment instead of an answer)

Comment: @AndyYan you can still upvote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can phone companies detect tethering (incl. Wifi hotspot)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47819/how-can-phone-companies-detect-tethering-incl-wifi-hotspot)